# TCP and UDP behavior

Tags: tcp, udp, streaming, wireshark, traffic

I am experimenting with TCP and UDP protocols for video streaming and I have observed something. I run Wireshark in the background to capture the traffic. The number of packets per sec is consistent. During video streaming, I introduce a network failure. There is no data flowing during a failure. As soon as the connection's back, the number of packets per sec is twice as more than before the failure for about 1-2 secs and then it is consistent. I am not able to figure why. It'd be really helpful if anyone could help me understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are introducing the network outage. if it is at client level, wouldn't you expect non-video communication to get started at the same time when network is back up? If you are filtering on video packets only, is there a cache setup where the chunks of video segments are downloaded periodically?

Comment: So the setup is something like this. Two PCs are connected to a router and I introduce failure by disconnecting the cable of the source PC to the router. As soon as I disconnect the  cable, wireshark captures ARP, DNS and ICMP packets and not any TCP/UDP data packets and once I reconnect it, it captures the data packets. When this happens, the number of packets per sec is way higher.